Is versal deformation with non-isomorphic fibers semi-universal?
I consider algebraic varieties over an algebraically closed fiekd $k$.
Let $f\colon X\to T$ be a smooth projective morphism. Fix a point $0\in T$. Assume that $f$ is a versal deformation of the fiber $X_0$, and for every point $t\neq 0$, the fiber $X_t$ is not isomorphic to $X_0$. Question 1: is $f$ a semi-universal deformation of $X_0$?
If it helps, I can assume that $H^{2}(X_0,T_{X_{0}})=0$.
I use the following terminology, taken from Sernesi's book "Deformations of algebraic schemes" (I hope I understood it correctly). A deformation $f$ as above is versal if for any flat morphism $f'\colon X'\to T'$, where $(T',0)$ is a spectrum of a finitely generated $k$-algebra and the fiber $X'_{0}$ is isomorphic to $X_0$, there is a morphism $\alpha\colon (T',0)\to (T,0)$ such that $f'$ is a pullback of $f$ along $\alpha$. It is semi-universal if additionally the differential of $\alpha$ is uniquely determined by $f'$.
Here are my thoughts so far, I am not sure if anything is correct.
If $X_0$ already has some semi-universal deformation $g\colon Y\to S$, then the answer is positive. Indeed, since $g$ is versal, we have $f=\alpha^{*}g$ for some $\alpha\colon (S,0)\to (T,0)$, and since $X_t\not\cong X_0$ for $t\neq 0$, we have $\alpha^{-1}(0)=0$. Since $f$ is versal, we have $g=\beta^{*}f$ for some $\beta\colon (S,0)\to (T,0)$, so $g=(\alpha\circ \beta)^{*}g$, and thus $d(\alpha\circ\beta)=\mathrm{id}$ by semi-universality of $g$. In particular, $d\alpha$ is surjective, so $\alpha$ is a local isomorphism, as needed.
If $k=\mathbb{C}$ and we consider alaytic deformations instead (so semi-universal ones exist by Kuranishi) then an apparently easy Satz 5.2(a) in  Flenner's "Ein Kriterium für die Offenheit der Versalität" shows that if $X_0$ has a versal deformation, it has a semi-universal one, too. So it is natural to ask the following question 2: is this statement true algebraically, over an algebraically closed field $k$, of arbitrary characteristic?
Schlessinger criterion implies that there is an infinitesimal semi-universal deformation of $X_0$. I am aware of the fact that there are usually more infinitesimal deformations than algebraic ones. However, in my setting I already have an algebraic versal deformation. To answer Question 1, I only need to check that its Kodaira-Spencer map $\kappa$ is injective.
Hence it seems natural to do the following: suppose $\kappa(v)=0$, and take a smooth curve $C\subseteq T$ tangent to $v$. By assumption, $f|_{C}$ is non-trivial, but it induces a trivial first-order deformation. I think that the latter means that it comes from a vector field tangent to $X_0$. If $k=\mathbb{C}$ then I could integrate this field and get, as time $t$ flow, an isomorphism $X_0\cong X_t$. But I cannot make this argument in positive characteristic.
To answer Question 2, I tried to follow Flenner's argument. I think that, applying Schlessinger criterion as above, we get a formally semi-universal deformation, which can be viewed as a deformation over $\operatorname{Spec} \hat{A}$ for some complete $k$-algebra $\hat{A}$. Write $T=\operatorname{Spec} B$, and let $\hat{B}$ be its completion, so $f$ pulls back to a formally versal deformation $\hat{f}\colon \hat{X}\to\operatorname{Spec} \hat{B}$. It is a general fact that $\hat{B}$ is a formal power series ring over $\hat{A}$, i.e. $\hat{B}=\hat{A}[\![x_1,\dots,x_n ]\!]$. Choose $y_i\in B$ in the preimage of $x_i$, and consider a finitely generated $k$-algebra $A:= B/(y_1,\dots,y_n)$. Its completion equals $\hat{A}$. We would like to prove that the pullback of $f$ to $\operatorname{Spec} A$, call it $g$, is semi-universal. We already know that it is formally semi-universal, so it is enough to prove that it is versal. To do this, for any f.g. local $k$-algebra $R$ and a deformation $h\colon Z\to \operatorname{Spec} R$ of $X_0$ we need to construct a morphism $\alpha\colon \operatorname{Spec} R\to \operatorname{Spec} A$ such that $h=\alpha^{*}g$. That is, we need a local homomorphism $A\to R$. We have local homomorphisms $\hat{\alpha}\colon \hat{A}\to \hat{R}$ and $\beta\colon B\to R$ such that the induced homomorphism $\hat{\beta}\colon \hat{B}\to \hat{R}$ extends $\hat{\alpha}$, and $\hat{h}=\hat{\alpha}^{*}\hat{g}$, $h=\beta^{*}g$; where $\hat{h}$, $\hat{g}$ are pullbacks of $h,g$ by $R\to \hat{R}$, $A\to\hat{A}$. I don't know how to construct $\alpha$; I think it is at this point when Flenner uses $k=\mathbb{C}$ and some analytic argument.
